# ImageMagick gif transform breaking

Tags: imagick

It seems that suddenly my image transforms are breaking gif animations. Weirdly, things were working fine for a couple of weeks and only recently I've been unable to upload new animated gifs. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8k2mx3lysjczi1g/Screenshot%202015-11-20%2014.38.11.png?dl=0

You can see that when the gif is transformed, the frames are overlapping and resized differently from frame to frame. I'm not sure what caused this (perhaps a craft update?), but after hours of research I'm wondering if imagick needs a +repage when it reconstructs the animation after the transform... this problem seems related to canvas size... maybe? But I can't find where Craft is sending the command to ImageMagick, so can't experiment w/ the animation settings.

Another weird quirk of this bug is if I have `'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,` set in my general config file, the page fails to load beyond the gif asset that's causing problems w/ the transform.

Anyone know what's going on here? I'm at a total loss...

Comment: Does it happen with all animated GIFs or just that one?  Can you send original source for the one in your screenshot over to support@craftcms.com?

Comment: It happens for any gif animation I've tried to upload in the last couple of weeks. There are a few on the site that were uploaded prior to this bug which are still working fine. I'll send the files & source over to support now. Thanks!